# Why some GitHub actions stopped executing?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have 3 workflows, that validate a directory/file each one (web, server, dockers).

Everything worked fine, until I added a "labeler" workflows to label PRs with web/server/docker labels.

The labeler workflow:

```yaml
name: "Pull Request Labeler"
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, labeled, unlabeled]

jobs:
  labeler:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/labeler@v3
        with:
          repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

One of the workflows that stopped working:

```yaml
name: Server validation

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
    paths:
      - ./server
      - .github/workflows/server-validation.yml
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    paths:
      - ./server
      - .github/workflows/server-validation.yml

jobs:
  validation:
    name: Server validation
# ...
```

Is there anything wrong? I didn't change the directory structure, the master branch name, or the workflow file.

This is the repository, where only the "labeler" workflow is executing: https://github.com/ivancea/autostocklist/actions

It has been happened since the last week, so I'm discarding any GitHub temporary problem.

Comment: Did you try informing the paths that way: `'server/**'` and `'**/server-validation.yml'` in the workflow not triggering? (I just find strange it was working before adding this new workflow, and not after anymore).

Comment: It was the "./", yes. Thanks. I don't know was it working before. Maybe it was just my impression because I changed the workflow itself in nearly every PR, and it was that change what triggered it. Solved! (Post an answer with that if you want to mark it as the answer)

Comment: As you have other triggers configured, it may have been started with any push or pull request to the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inform the paths that way:

```yaml
paths:
   - 'server/**'
   - '**/server-validation.yml'
```

Instead of using something like `./**`.